# Override Id column's auto-increment initial value with Fluent nHibernate AutoMapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, auto-increment, automapping

I'm using Fluent nHibernate AutoMapping for a project and would like to change the initial Id value for one table in my schema from 1 to say 1000 (all other tables I would like to remain with the default behaviour of starting the Id at 1).

I'm guessing that I need to specify this in my IIDConvetion, but am not sure how?

```
public class PrimaryKeyConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Id");
        instance.GeneratedBy.Native();
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not supported yet. Your best bet is to implement `IAuxiliaryDatabaseObject` and set the starting value of the identity to 1000 with sql then add it as last element to the configuration object.